# Reading of matrix from file

Tags: c++, matrix, file-handling

I am again here with this query.
In the following code, I initialize my matrix with all values equals zero and after it, I write this matrix in a text file. Now I want to read that matrix from the file and put all the values in another matrix named arr1[][] and when I print it on the screen I got a blank screen why?

Please help me thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n = 10;
    int m = 10;

    int arr[10][10];
    int arr1[10][10];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = 0; // here i initialized my matrix with all values zero.
        }

    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("array.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            fout << arr[i][j]; // here i write it into the file
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    fout.close();

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("array.txt");

    if (!fin)
    {
        cerr << std::strerror(errno) << "\n"; // handle open errors
    }

    fin >> n >> m;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            fin >> arr[i][j]; // now here i read the matrix and put it into the
            // different matrix.
            arr1[i][j] = arr[i][j];
        }

    fin.close();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            cout << arr1[i][j]; // when i print it to the screen i got black screen
            // but i wants
            // a matrx which written in the file.
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you inspected the file after writing to it to see if it contains valid numbers? I think you'll find they're not delimited with spaces or newlines.

Comment: yes, they saved as a single line of zero, how to solve this problem can u edit my code, please?

Comment: Think about it. `fout << arr[i][j];` What would you have to do to get a space after the number?

Comment: Also be aware you never write out `n` and `m`, so what do think this will do `fin >> n >> m;`

Comment: You do not write array’s size, but you try to read it.

Comment: can you edit my code please?

Comment: When you try to read array’s size, both `m` and `n` are zero for you did not save them in the first place, so you read the first two elements of the array, which are zero. - You deleted the comment where you said you added a tab between elements.

Comment: ` fin >> n >> m;` this line is culprit , you are reading size from file but you havent store, either you store or comment this line as per your requirement

Comment: if you need i will write modified code in answer

Comment: please modify my code